# Best framework to write build scripts

Tags: build-script

Some of basic requirements are:

1. Basic build scripts requirements like pulling from scm, copying, compiling :)
2. Compatibility on Windows, Unix (Solaris, HPUX, AIX) and Linux.

I have heard of several good options like scons, ant etc but would like to know what is your favorite choice?
Currently I have 36 kornshell scripts which i need to port as kornshell is not supported properly even in SubSystem for UNIX in windows.

Answer (score 1):

My vote goes for cmake. It is important for me that it is a meta buildsystem.

> CMake generates native makefiles and workspaces that can be used in the compiler environment of your choice.

Linux users work with eclipse, windows user with visual studio.
I also considered scons with the full power of python behind it but as stated in the [scons wiki](http://www.scons.org/wiki/SconsVsOtherBuildTools#head-3d0faf3f1d4d3b73f31eaa0ba97d4df18a474369):

> To sum up, my very subjective opinion is that scons is a better idea, but CMake has a stronger implementation